# Using JAXB to parse GPX

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, gpx

I'm trying to parse a GPX file using JAXBU here is my code:

```
GpxType unmarshal(String path) {

    GpxType list = new GpxType();
    try {
        javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext jaxbCtx = javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
                  .newInstance(list.getClass().getPackage().getName());
        javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbCtx.createUnmarshaller();
        list = (GpxType) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new java.io.File(path)); //NOI18N
        return list;
    } catch (javax.xml.bind.JAXBException ex) {
        // XXXTODO Handle exception
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("global")
                    .log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex); //NOI18N
    }
    return null;
}
```

however i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
                  javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cannot be cast to GPXfiles.GpxType
```

so im guessing its because using JAXBU its looking for a XML file instead of a GPX file. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can call `JAXBIntrospector.getValue(Object)` on the result of the `unmarshal` operation to guard against the result being wrapped in a `JAXBElement`.

Comment: Im guessing you mean put it in this line? `list = (GpxType) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new java.io.File(path)); //NOI18N`